# need selenium web driver code for delete

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

[image: table image]

i tried this one:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//a[contains(.,'terw')]")).findElement(By.xpath(".//img[@id='delete_fully_img'])")).click();
```

but its not working, my code:

```
 <table id="Table_1" class="dataTable" aria-describedby="Table_1_info" style="width: 100px;">
<thead>
    <tr class="header" role="row">
        <td class="sorting_disabled" role="columnheader" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 213px;">Point Name</td>
        <td class="sorting_disabled" role="columnheader" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 149px;">Description</td>
        <td class="sorting_disabled" role="columnheader" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 150px;">Date Added</td>
        <td class="sorting_disabled" role="columnheader" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 46px;"/>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody role="alert" aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="all">
    <tr class="odd">
        <td class=" ">
            <a id="attachment_title_382" slider_number="0" onclick="AddPoints('edit', '382', '');" href="javascript:void(0);">terw</a>
        </td>
        <td class=" "/>
        <td class=" ">02/21/2017</td>
        <td class=" ">
            <img id="delete_fully_img" onclick="deletePoint('', '382', '382', '0');" title="Delete Point" style="height:17px;width:17px;" src="http //close_icon.png"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="even">
        <td class=" ">
            <a id="attachment_title_301" slider_number="0" onclick="AddPoints('edit', '301', '1');" href="javascript:void(0);">1</a>
        </td>
        <td class=" "/>
        <td class=" ">02/15/2017</td>
        <td class=" ">
            <img id="delete_fully_img_1" onclick="deletePoint('', '301', '301', '0');" title="Delete Point" style="height:17px;width:17px;" src="http //close_icon.png"/"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Question is not clear , please add extra details or delete the question if it has been asked by mistake.

Comment: By mistake?  Does that actually happen?  I just wonder if someone comes over to this site and goes "oops, I just put this all here by mistake."

Comment: Read Post. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try any of these below code.

**Explanation:** Using class attribute of `tr`tag, try to first locate element text like `02/21/2017` using `text` method. Then move ahead with `img` tag using `following` keyword.

```
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr[@class='odd']/td[contains(text(), '02/21/2017')]/..//following::img[@id='delete_fully_img']")).click();
```

OR

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr[@class='odd']/..//following::img[@id='delete_fully_img']")).click();
```

OR

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@id='delete_fully_img']")).click();
```

OR

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr[@class='odd']//img[@id='delete_fully_img']")).click();
```

OR

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr[@class='odd']//child::img[@id='delete_fully_img']")).click();
```

Comment: thanks it worked,in this driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr[@class='odd']/td[contains(text(), '02/21/2017')]/..//following::img[@id='delete_fully_img']")).click();  is it possible to put name instead of date?

Comment: No, You can't put name because your `td` tag contains only `date` here. See html `<td>02/21/2017</td>`And If it's resolved your answer then please mark this answer as accepted.

Comment: I have created new `xpath`. but it is more complex to understand. try this xpath :- `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr[@class='odd']/td/a[contains(text(), 'terw')]/..//following-sibling::td[contains(text(), '02/21/2017')]/..//following-sibling::td/img[@id='delete_fully_img']")).click();`

Answer (score 0):

Use the xpath :
//tr[contains(@class,"even")]//td/img[contains(@id,"delete_fully_img_1") and contains(@title,"Delete Point")]
Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this below:-

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@id='delete_fully_img']"))
```

OR

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr[@class='odd']//img[@id='delete_fully_img']"))
```

OR

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@id='delete_fully_img']/ancestor::tr[@class='odd']"))
```

Comment: Hello @Paras, Your both xpath will not work, because you are targeting `a` tag. but inside the `html` that id attribute contains with `img` tag.

Comment: your last xpath will not work here, because your xpath will locate the entire row, so here instead of using `ancestor` keyword use `child` keyword, so it will locate only particular delete icon button. see my last answer with `child` keyword.